# Sliding Menu white space

Tags: android

I'm using  jfeinstein10  Sliding Menu library in my project and everything works fine, is just that when I run my app on certain devices there is a white space in the top of the fragment that holds the listview, here is a pic:

[image]

Here is the code where I set up the sliding menu:

```
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
    FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragMenu = new FragmentMenu();
    fragTransaction.replace(R.id.menu_frame, fragMenu);
    fragTransaction.commit();

    SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
    sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.actionbar_home_width);
    setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);

    final ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And this would be the XML file of my fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/fondoRowsMenuIzquierdo" >

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/fondoRowsMenuIzquierdo"
    android:childDivider="@color/fondoRowsChildMenuIzquierdo"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/separadoresMenuIzquierdo"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:groupIndicator="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone knows how to remove that white space?

Comment: please show your layout xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem updating to the latest SlidingMenu library : https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu. but another problem came with this update.

In SlidingMenu.java there is this piece of code:

```
public void manageLayers(float percentOpen) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) return;

    boolean layer = percentOpen > 0.0f && percentOpen < 1.0f;
    final int layerType = layer ? View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE : View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE;

    if (layerType != getContent().getLayerType()) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.v(TAG, "changing layerType. hardware? " + (layerType == View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE));
                getContent().setLayerType(layerType, null);
                getMenu().setLayerType(layerType, null);
                if (getSecondaryMenu() != null) {
                    getSecondaryMenu().setLayerType(layerType, null);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

If you are using this library in HONEYCOMB or previous API versions this code won't let you interact with the view in the sliding menu,you have  yo change this validation:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) return;
```

for this:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of the colors.xml in the Sliding Menu library

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked the following:

In Your-project/.../slidingmenu/src/com.slidingmenu.lib/SlidingMenu.java

```
protected boolean fitSystemWindows(Rect insets) {
```

where there are

```
int topPadding = getPaddingTop() + insets.top;
int bottomPadding = getPaddingBottom() + insets.bottom;
```

Add the following:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    topPadding = insets.top;
 }
```

You can fix as well the bottomPadding or any other padding if your problem is there. If your problem is related to a bottom navigation bar you could check the height and fix the padding in the same file adding this:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Resources resources = getContent().getResources();
        int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            bottomPadding += resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
    }
```